# Function returning array is not allowed in Linux kernel

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, linux-kernel

After cloning the Linux kernel and opening up for example /drivers/md/dm-zero.c in VSCode (with the C CPP extension) gives me an error at the last 3 lines saying: `function returning array is not allowed`.

Of course I know that this should not be an error since I just cloned and didn't adjust anything. Is there a setting in the C CPP extension that should be set?

Thanks!

Edit: The title is misleading: I know this has nothing to do with the kernel itself, but I wanted to specify that VSCode complains about something that was already written in the Linux Kernel source code

Edit2:
The specific error is in these 3 lines: function returning array is not allowed C/C++(91)

```
MODULE_AUTHOR("Jana Saout <jana@saout.de>");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION(DM_NAME " dummy target returning zeros");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

`MODULE_AUTHOR` for example expands to

```
#define __MODULE_INFO(tag, name, info)                    \
    static const char __UNIQUE_ID(name)[]                 \
        __used __section(".modinfo") __aligned(1)         \
        = __MODULE_INFO_PREFIX __stringify(tag) "=" info
```

I use GCC in Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: That's not a kernel limitation. It's a limitation of the language. Show a snippet of the code you are trying to compile and someone can probably help you to work around that problem.

Comment: Just do not do it. Think about where in memory you should save the returned array, and you may notice the problems (and in kernel they are huge problems). Just allocate the buffer and sent it as pointer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I know it's not a kernel limitation. Sorry for the misleading title. What I meant is that I cloned the Linux kernel, and while it compiles just fine, the C/CPP extension in VSCode complains about the problem I described above. I wanted to know if there is something I need to do to make the extension compatible with how the kernel is written

Comment: If you don't post the code the compiler pointed out, then how can we tell? Also what compiler are you using in which environment? Only knowing your IDE is not very helpful.

Comment: How does VSCode complain? Is it during compilation (then it is actually not VSCode, but the compiler you are using) or is the editor just showing some hints?

Comment: I didn't post the code because it's a lot of nested preprocessor macros:
Check the edited post for the code :D

Comment: @Gerhardh it's just the editor showing error hints. The kernel compiles just fine. That's why I know the editor should not be flagging any error, but I don't know if it's because of a setting in the extension I should change, or something else.

Answer (score 1):

[This comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/5588#issuecomment-662116156) in the vscode github repo solved the issue for me. Basically need to add some explicit include paths and compiler args to the `c_cpp_properties.json` file.

```json
"includePath": [
  "/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-39-generic/arch/x86/include",
  "/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-39-generic/arch/x86/include/generated",
  "/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-39-generic/include",
  "/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-39-generic/arch/x86/include/uapi",
  "/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-39-generic/arch/x86/include/generated/uapi",
  "/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-39-generic/include/uapi",
  "/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-39-generic/include/generated/uapi",
  "/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-39-generic/ubuntu/include",
  "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include"
],
"compilerArgs": [
  "-nostdinc",
  "-include", "/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-39-generic/include/linux/kconfig.h",
  "-include", "/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-39-generic/include/linux/compiler_types.h"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

> `/drivers/md/dm-zero.c`

...

> gives me an error at the last 3 lines

I assume you mean following?

```c
MODULE_AUTHOR("Jana Saout <jana@saout.de>");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION(DM_NAME " dummy target returning zeros");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

These are macros'es and they are absolutely valid if you dig up and look for their definition. The errors which you get is something local to VSCode and their C/C++ extension (whatever that is), due to its inability to find a definition.

Comment: Thanks :D But the extension can find the definition. In fact (see my edited post) it gives me another error which I think, should not be flagged as an error, because it should be working code since I cloned it freshly from the repo

Answer (score 0):

I fixed those by adding two `define` values in `c_cpp_properties.json`.

```
"defines": [ "__KERNEL__", "MODULE" ]
```